# Creating an array in Python while conserving line format

Tags: python, arrays

I have a file that is in the following format style:

```
unitig_19 <tab> . <tab> region  13221    13240  0.00    + <tab> . <tab> cov2=.....
unitig_19 <tab> . <tab> region  13241    13260  0.00    + <tab> . <tab> cov2=.....
unitig_19 <tab> . <tab> region  13261    13280  0.00    + <tab> . <tab> cov2=.....
```

And so on.

How can I create an array while conserving the format and not having all the information jammed into one massive line? Something like this:

```
[unitig_19, ., region, 13221, 13240, 0.00, +, ., cov2=.....]
[unitig_19, ., region, 13241, 13260, 0.00, +, ., cov2=.....]
[unitig_19, ., region, 13261, 13280, 0.00, +, ., cov2=.....]
```

My goal is to afterwards extract specific pieces from each line array.

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Check out the [string.split()](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.split) method.  You could split each line on the `'\t'` literal as your read them in from the file.

Comment: I see three options: `string.split()` (simple way to convert line to list of strings), `re.split()` (can split on multiple separators) or the `csv` module.

Comment: Looks like the csv module did the trick and was the best option. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can use regex with `re.split` function :

```
>>> s="""unitig_19 <tab> . <tab> region  13221    13240  0.00    + <tab> . <tab> cov2=
... unitig_19 <tab> . <tab> region  13241    13260  0.00    + <tab> . <tab> cov2=
... unitig_19 <tab> . <tab> region  13261    13280  0.00    + <tab> . <tab> cov2="""
>>> import re
>>> [[i for i in j if i] for j in [re.split(r'<.*?>| {1,}',line) for line in s.split('\n')]]
[['unitig_19', '.', 'region', '13221', '13240', '0.00', '+', '.', 'cov2='], 
 ['unitig_19', '.', 'region', '13241', '13260', '0.00', '+', '.', 'cov2='],
 ['unitig_19', '.', 'region', '13261', '13280', '0.00', '+', '.', 'cov2=']]
```

*Note* that if `<tab>`'s are `\t` you need to change the `<.*?>` in your pattern to `\t`.

Comment: I think each `<tab>` in the OP refers to a `'\t'`.

Comment: Your output looks wrong... all the values are repeated. I think it should rather be `[re.split(r'<.*?>',line) for line in s.splitlines()]` (`line` instead of `s` in the first `split`, and a `?` for non-greedy match -- but those should probably be `\t` anyway)

Comment: @tobias_k Yep, fixed!